# How to handle disconnect event in AWS IOT?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I'm doing real-time update in my web application. The application connects to AWS IOT using [aws-iot-device-sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js):

```
const client = awsIot.device({
    region: awsConfig.region,
    protocol: 'wss',
    accessKeyId: <accessKey>,
    secretKey: <secretKey>,
    sessionToken: <sessionToken>,
    port: 443,
    host: <iotEndpoint>
});

client.on('connect', res => {
    // ok
});
```

Then I send request to my API for creating a record in database table which contains IOT topic id. Then application subcribes to this topic id:

```
client.subscribe(topicId)
```

I want to delete records in database when client disconnects from IOT. How should I do that? I see that there is a [disconnect event](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/life-cycle-events.html) in IOT. But I don't understand how to handle this event in AWS lambda.

Comment: You appear to have done all the research and understand what IoT mechanism to use (although you could also look into using LWT records). What specifically is your question? Are you just looking for help writing a Lambda function which can update a database record?

Comment: I'm looking for help with running a lambda function when disconnect event is fired

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are asking how to trigger a Lambda function when the client disconnects.

1. Create the Lambda function you want to be triggered by this event, and deploy it to AWS. (Open another question if you are stuck on this part).
2. Go into the IoT console and create a new rule with the following Rule Query Statement: `SELECT * FROM '$aws/events/presence/disconnected/#'`
3. For the rule's action, select "Invoke Lambda Function" and then select the Lambda function you deployed previously.

Comment: I struggled for nearly 2hrs to know that topic name is what you have mentioned and not what AWS advisory has (they obfuscate with <clientId>). phew!
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/life-cycle-events.html#connect-disconnect